# Git URL for a Bitbucket repo not showing

Tags: git, github, bitbucket

I have a strange thing going on. Someone gave me a repo on a linux box, when I do:

```
$ git status 
On branch master
nothing to commit, working directory clean
```

This means it is a Git repo, I tried to find the remote URL for this repo using:

```
$ git config --get remote.origin.url
```

It doesn't show me anything. Also if I do:

```
$ git remote show origin
fatal: 'origin' does not appear to be a git repository
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

Comment: add also gitconfige content

Comment: I believe your local key has become out of sync with what you have on Bitbucket

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the repo only created locally. Not linked with the remote.

Try run `git remote -v` it will give the details of remote. If it doesn't show you anything. That means the repo is not linked with the remote. If this is the case linked the remote with your local repo by running

```
git remote add origin <your_repo_url>
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe that your public key has somehow become out of sync with the one you have installed on BitBucket.  Try these steps:

From your Git bash locally, do

```
$ cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
```

This will output your public key to console.  Keep the bash open, because you will need this key later on.

Next, go to the Bitbucket website and login.  Click the person icon from the upper left side of BitBucket and choose "Bitbucket settings".  Then, from the left side menu choose `SECURITY <- SSH keys`, and you should see something like this:

[image]

Click "Add key", which will generate a popup looking like this:

[image]

Give the key a name and paste the dump from your Git bash here.  **Make sure that the first line has the text ssh-rsa**  Your actual key should pasted on the *second* line.

Click "Add key."

The error message should go away.  You can delete the old key(s) if you want, but you don't have to.

Comment: Thanks Tim for bringing this to light , i will do check on this asap

Comment: It's not me who downvoted your answer, but I guess why they did - the fact that `git config --get remote.origin.url` doesn't output anything suggests that right now the problem is not the one that you suspect (though it is possible, that after correctly configuring `remote.origin.url` the author of the question will also have to setup the SSH key).